# Postgres on App Engine Standard - Error on insert

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine

App engine standard only supports python 2 and libraries must be pure python so I'm connecting to a Postgres instance using SQLAlchemy and pg8000 (pure python as opposed to psycopg2 which is not). The connection is made without any trouble, but when an insert is attempted I get the following error which I don't fully understand:

```
<type 'memoryview'> has type <type 'memoryview'>, but expected one of: str, unicode
```

Snippet of code that causes this behavior:

```
event = self.generate_view(body)
self.write_event(event, ViewEvent)

def write_event(self, event, event_model):
    session = Session()
    success = False
    try:
        new_event = event_model(**event)
        session.add(new_event)
        session.commit()
        logging.info('Generated event {}'.format(event))
        success = True
    except Exception, e:
        session.rollback()
        logging.debug('Error inserting event {}'.format(event))
        logging.debug('Error was {}'.format(e))
    finally:
        session.close()
    return success
```

Any help would be much appreciated - or if you have had success connecting Postgres to App Engine Standard I'm open to any alternate solutions than just using pg8000.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add `ssl=True` to your db connection.

```
pg8000.connect(ssl=True, **config)
```

Or in SQLAlchemy:

```
create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://user:pass@hostname/dbname', connect_args={'ssl': True}, echo=True)
```